# Block undo keyboard commands of Flutter's TextField for custom implementation

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm developing an app with Flutter that includes TextField widgets for text input. My aim is to handle undo and redo manually with a custom implementation, bypassing Flutter's built-in features.

Here's my issue: even though I've tried wrapping the TextField with widgets like RawKeyboardListener to capture keyboard events, it seems like TextField still manages undo and redo internally. Is there another way to block these and do a custom implementation?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an **UndoHistoryController** to TextField. UndoHistoryController is a **ValueNotifier** that notifies attached listeners of changes in **UndoHistoryValue**.

create an instance of UndoHistoryController.

```
 final UndoHistoryController undoController = UndoHistoryController();
```

Pass it to a TextField, listen to that instance using a **ValueListenableBuilder** and return a row on buttons in the builder to perform undo/redo operations.

Here are example for better understanding

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

 return  Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      TextField(
        controller: controller,
        focusNode: focusNode,
        undoController: undoController,
      ),
      ValueListenableBuilder<UndoHistoryValue>(
        valueListenable: undoController,
        builder: (BuildContext context, UndoHistoryValue value,
            Widget? child) {
          return Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                child: Text('Undo'),
                onPressed: () {
                  undoController.undo();
                },
              ),
              TextButton(
                child: Text('Redo'),
                onPressed: () {
                  undoController.redo();
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
 );
}
```

Clicking the Undo and Redo buttons will remove and reapply changes from the TextField value respectively

Comment: Respectfully, how does this answer my question? I’m not asking how to do an undo/redo, I’m asking to stop flutter’s implementation of it from executing.

Answer (score 2):

Updated: I've added more possibilities to the code. I've created two functions for preventing such actions.
1st one is for the undo action & 2nd one is for the redo action.

What we're doing is that whenever the user performs an undo or a redo operation, we're blocking that operation from happening.

We've created our function over there. So, whenever the user performs an undo operation at that time, the `preventPerformingUndo()` function will call & whenever the user performs a redo operation at that time, the `preventPerformingRedo()` function will call.

Source code:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:flutter/services.dart";

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(home: MyWidget());
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  final TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    textEditingController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RawKeyboardListener(
              focusNode: FocusNode(),
              onKey: (RawKeyEvent value) {
                // For Control & Command Key
                final bool isControlPressed = value.isControlPressed;
                final bool isMetaPressed = value.isMetaPressed;
                final bool isControlOrMeta = isControlPressed || isMetaPressed;

                // For Z Key
                final bool isLZ = value.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.keyZ;
                final bool isPZ = value.physicalKey == PhysicalKeyboardKey.keyZ;
                final bool isLogicalOrPhysicalZ = isLZ || isPZ;

                // For Y Key
                final bool isLY = value.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.keyY;
                final bool isPY = value.physicalKey == PhysicalKeyboardKey.keyY;
                final bool isLogicalOrPhysicalY = isLY || isPY;

                if (isControlOrMeta && isLogicalOrPhysicalZ) {
                  preventPerformingUndo();
                } else {}

                if (isControlOrMeta && isLogicalOrPhysicalY) {
                  preventPerformingRedo();
                } else {}
              },
              child: TextField(
                controller: textEditingController,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: preventPerformingUndo,
                  child: const Text("Perform Undo"),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: preventPerformingRedo,
                  child: const Text("Perform Redo"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void preventPerformingUndo() {
    // What to do if user pressed Ctrl + Z
    return;
  }

  void preventPerformingRedo() {
    // What to do if user pressed Ctrl + Y
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Same question I put under the above response, but respectfully, how does this answer my question? I’m not asking how to do an undo/redo, I’m asking to stop flutter’s implementation of it from executing.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience & misunderstanding. I've updated my answer. Kindly check it out.

Comment: I tried the code and still the default behavior of Ctrl + Z happens.

Comment: I updated my answer & I've added more possibilities to the code.
Kindly test it out.

Comment: This still doesn't perform in the expected way, clearly showing you did not test it. While I can't be 100% certain, this looks nearly Identical to what would be generated by ChatGPT or another LLM (I would know, I tried before asking for human help)

Comment: I assure you that the above-written code is 100% mine & I did not use any AI tool. And I tested the code in my system & it was working & providing the expected result. I have a MacOS system. So, in my case, I've command+z & command+y. But I did code for Windows system also that has control+z & control+y.